# change the color of a selected portion of a view with LongGestureRecognizer in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I am having an app in which I am using UILongPressGestureRecognizer.

What I want is that, When user touches any portion of a view for 3 seconds, only that portion of a view should change its color.

If user touches another part of a View, then that portion should also change its color.

I am trying the below code.

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                          initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 2.0; //seconds
    lpgr.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];

-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
  CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0, 200, 200);
    UIView * backgroundView;
     backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
     [backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:204./255 green:213./255 blue:216./255 alpha:0.5]];
     [self.view addSubview:backgroundView];
}
```

With this code I can only change the color of that frame set.

But how to change the color of only some part of a screen which user touches?

Is it possible to do so?

If yes, How can I do this?

Please help me.

**Edited**

I got the location co-ordinates with the below codes but how to find "Touch Area" means height and width of that touched portion?

Please tell me if anyone knows about it.

Is this possible?

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One way to do the same, get the X & Y location on longpress and set the frame x, y, width and height instead of 0 & 0 as X & Y. You can try configuring width and height to some 5 pixels.

Comment: Can you please explain with an answer?

Comment: did you want to view only the last area the user have touche, or all areas ?

Comment: @Manthan please find my solution below.

Comment: All areas which user touches via finger

Comment: @Shan: Can we meet after an hour?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, i didn't test it. But it should work.
As i understood you need to highlight parts before second press event is called...

```
-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    //check if old highlight exists and remove if true
UIView *oldView = [self.view viewWithTag:999];
if(oldView != nil)
    [oldView removeFromSuperView];

CGPoint location = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(location.X-100, location.Y-100, 200, 200);
UIView * backgroundView;
backgroundView.tag = 999; //mark view as highlight 
backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:204./255 green:213./255 blue:216./255 alpha:0.5]];
[self.view addSubview:backgroundView];
}
```

// another case

```
-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{

UIView *oldView = [self.view viewWithTag:999];
CGPoint location = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];

for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews)
{
   if(CGRectContainsPoint([subview.frame], location))
   {
            CGRect frame = subview.frame;
            UIView * backgroundView;
            backgroundView.tag = 999; //mark view as highlight 
            backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
            [backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:204./255 green:213./255 blue:216./255 alpha:0.5]];
            [self.view addSubview:backgroundView];
   }
}
}
```

Comment: But how to give height and width dynamically which user touches?

Comment: There are errors in your code. Please check and edit your code. There is no method called Set.

Comment: i don't have mac nearby and i cant check syntax highlight.... Play around with code...

Answer (score 0):

You can find the touch location like shown below,

```
-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    CGPoint translatedPoint = [(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender translationInView:self.view];

    //continue here with your logic for changing color
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving the same is

```
-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    CGPoint location = [(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture locationInView:gesture.view];

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(location.x, location.y, 5, 5);
    // Rest is the same as you have mentiond in your code.
}
```

I have assumed width and height to be of 5 pixel each.
Hope it helps.

Comment: That is right but height and should be dynamic depending on user's touch. How to get that? Is it possible?

Comment: Don't you know how to get width and height? Any idea?

Comment: Sorry i am not sure about getting the actual width and height.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my proposal. Create a specific UIView (longPressView) and set it as your background view in your view controller.

here is code for this view.

```
//  longPressView.h
//  Created by Armand DOHM on 10/03/2014.
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface longPressView : UIView
-(void) longPressAt:(CGPoint)locationInView;
@end
```

>

```
//  longPressView.m
//  Created by Armand DOHM on 10/03/2014.
#import "longPressView.h"

@interface longPressView ()
  @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *pressLocations;
@end

@implementation longPressView

-(NSArray *) pressLocations { //lazy instantiation
    if (!_pressLocations) {
        _pressLocations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return _pressLocations;
}

-(void) longPressAt:(CGPoint)locationInView {
    //save new touch
    [self.pressLocations addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:locationInView]];
    //refresh view (ask ios to call drawRect:)
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    //draw each touch

    CGFloat widthBox = 10.0;
    CGFloat heightBox = widthBox;

    for (NSValue *value in self.pressLocations) {
        CGPoint p = [value CGPointValue];
        CGRect boxRect = CGRectMake(p.x - (widthBox/2), p.y - (heightBox / 2), widthBox, heightBox);

        UIBezierPath *roundedRect = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:boxRect cornerRadius:10.0f];
        [[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.75] setFill];
        [roundedRect fill];
    }
}
@end
```

Now, in your view controller, import longPressView.h, set your UILongPressGestureRecognizer iBaction

```
#import "longPressView.h"


- (IBAction)didLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    longPressView *lpv = (longPressView *)self.view;
    [lpv longPressAt:[sender locationInView:self.view]];

}
```

Enjoy ;-D  PS : if the user longPress and move his finger, a special effect will append...